# Make a TestNG test dependable on successfully finished test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am having some selenium TestNG tests written in Java, which are dependable on a first initial test, that registers a user into the tested platform and passes a tutorial, all other tests are using the login credentials from that initial test.

So far so good, I am also using a retry logic (IRetryAnalyzer): https://www.swtestacademy.com/retry-failed-tests-testng-iretryanalyzer/
to retry my failed tests up to 4-5 times, because the host server sometimes yields errors at random points, which can not be fixed atm.

If the initial (register) test fails the first 2 times, and passes on it's third execution, all further tests, which are dependable on it will fail with an exception:

```
 "java.lang.Throwable: depends on not successfully finished methods in group..."
```

So the test results will look like this:

Test A (Register) - failed.
Test A (Register) - failed.
Test A (Register) - passed.
Test B (Dependable on A)- failed.
Test C (Dependable on A) - failed.

Tests B and C are failing, because Test A initially failed the first time, so it's somehow recorded as a fail.
The question is - can the dependable tests be made in a way, that they only depend on the passed instance of Test A, or at least try to execute them despite of the fact, that Test A failed a couple of times.

Note that using a priority parameter is not an option to consider in this scenario.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'alwaysRun' argument. Attach it to Test B

Example

> @Test(alwaysRun = true, groups = { "random_group" })

Comment: Thank you, this always runs the tests, while keeping them dependable on the group, however it does not cover the case, in which there is an issue in the initial test A and it fails all the time - the tests B and C are still run, although test A is failed.
Still, it proves to be a solution for 99% of the cases.